# What happens if I use chrome.storage.sync, but the user is not logged in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I read the `chrome.storage` API docs. I saw that if you are offline and you are trying to use `chrome.storage.sync`, data will save in local until you had internet again, but I want to know what happens if i try to use `chrome.storage.sync` and nobody is logged in Google Chrome.

What i read is that the data will be automatically synced with your user account. If there is nobody logged the data will save in local? Will the data save in a guest user (for example)?

Comment: And when i get logged, the data will be syn to my user or just in local?

Comment: The question is that if i am not logged, the data will synced in local. ok, but if i storage data using chrome.storage.syn wiith nobody logged, the data right now is in local, but, we change computer and other user use the computer and get logged, the data will be synced into this 2º user account?

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting question! I think you can try it yourself and post your findings in an answer.

Comment: I recently finished the test that i could do. I think that i can do it because my extension is not published, i use my extension offline, then i sing in with my user and in another computer i tried watch data in my profile but didnt appear. There is not reason for didn´t sync with user. I really think that if the extension is not published, the syn won't be able to do. I execute my extension again with internet and my user and i couldnt watch the data in the other computer so this is my theory. If my company keep going in this project and published the extension i will write again with result.

Comment: If the extension is loaded locally, it'll have different id on another computer, unless you add a `key` in manifest.json, see [Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](//stackoverflow.com/a/23877974)

Comment: Hmmm... that's arrive me at another question, if i load the extension in Owncloud, Dropbox (for example) and i syn my cloud and then i will install the extension, will be has the same ID? Hmmm

Answer (score 1):

As written in documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

"When Chrome is offline, Chrome stores the data locally. The next time the browser is online, Chrome syncs the data. **Even if a user disables syncing, storage.sync will still work. In this case, it will behave identically to storage.local.**"

Regarding data from storage being accessible by other user, that would be by default not possible as despite you're being logged in or not to Chrome, there is still separate directory structure for each user of computer.

Being on Windows 10, you should have it located in such location:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Extension Settings\<extension_ID>`